# how change a piece of Url with Textbox & Button?(Swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift

this is my code but its give me nil in output.

```
    import AVFoundation
    import AVKit
    import UIKit
    var userName :String?
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
         var movieUrl:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "http://streamapp.ir:1935/lahzenegar/\(userName)/playlist.m3u8")
         @IBOutlet var inpt: UITextField!
         @IBOutlet var scView: UIScrollView!
         let avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
         var avPlayer: AVPlayer?
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
  }
```

and my button code:

```
   @IBAction func playButtonTapped3(sender: UIButton) {

    userName = "\(self.inpt.text)"
    self.presentViewController(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()
    }
    print(movieUrl)
}
```

so i want when press button (username) change value to whatever users entered in textBox

[already output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI0AY.png)

thanks for help

Comment: i hope you get what i mean:)

Answer (score 0):

When you first create the movieURL the userName is not set. That is fine, however, when you press the button you need to update the movieURL as well as the username. Something like this:

```
userName = "\(self.inpt.text)"
movieURL = NSURL(string: "http://streamapp.ir:1935/lahzenegar/\(userName)/playlist.m3u8")
```